# Grouping Similar Strings in a long string [Python]

Tags: python, string

I have four or five strings that all have a sequence, i want to group them in a list.

For example:

```
cake/1/
cake/2/
big/1/
nice/1/
cake/3/
```

I need the cakes in a list, the big in a list and the nice in a list

Here's what i've tried.

```
res = [list(i) for j, i in groupby(y, lambda a: a.split('/')[0])]
```

This didn't work, I thought of using regex but i'm not sure if that's anything to move forward through.

Here's the expected output

```
[['cake/1/', 'cake/2/', 'cake/3/'], ['big/1/'], ['nice/1/']]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: and can you provide an example of expected output?

Comment: `res = [list(i) for j, i in groupby(y, lambda a: a.split('/')[0])] `

Comment: add it to the question please

Comment: An expected output would be `[['cake/1/', 'cake/2/', 'cake/3/'], ['big/1/'], ['nice/1/']]`

Comment: The group is for same substrings, not similar substrings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You was nearly right:

`groupby` is changing the group each time the key is changing:

`1112111` will be grouped as: `111 - 2 - 111`

So if you want to guarantee that all *your* groups will be joined in one, you should sort your list of strings first so all same first-words-strings will be nearby and will not be splitted by another first-words-strings:

```
y = [
    'cake/1/',
    'cake/2/',
    'big/1/',
    'nice/1/',
    'cake/3/'
]

res = [list(i) for j, i in groupby(sorted(y), lambda a: a.split('/')[0])]
                                     ^
                                     |
HERE --------------------------------+
```

> `[['big/1/'], ['cake/1/', 'cake/2/', 'cake/3/'], ['nice/1/']]`

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you. How would you do something similar similar in longer strings.

Comment: If you want some complicated sorting, you should use an argument `key` with lambda equal to lambda in groupby. P.S. If my answer helped you, I will be appreciated if you will accept/upvote it.

Comment: Can you share of an example of that? The lamba = lambda groupby thing.

Comment: `res = [list(i) for j, i in groupby(sorted(y, key=lambda a: a.split('/')[0]), lambda a: a.split('/')[0])]`

Comment: This doesn't work for my long string. What if i have thisiscakeforme/1/car and thisiscakeforme/2/car

Comment: Then you probably doing something wrong. I just copypasted and checked my code with your strings and everything works: `[['cake/2/', 'cake/3/'], ['thisiscakeforme/1/car', 'thisiscakeforme/2/car']]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194897/discussion-between-the-tech-nerd-and-vurmux).